# Why git do not take into account changes at working tree?

Tags: git, git-log

I run the command:

```
git log --topo-order -u -L 228,250:"lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/Wizard.pm"
```

To inspect changes at the `start` subroutine, but `git` do not take into account changes in working tree.

[image]

It seems I should supply lines as they are in last commit:

```
git stash save
git log --topo-order -u -L 212,234:"lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/Wizard.pm"
```

[image]

After that I can restore stash. And command still works (just lines in editor are different. See first picture):

```
git stash pop
git log --topo-order -u -L 212,234:"lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/Wizard.pm"
```

**Is there an option that will show evolution for lines that are not committed yet?**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your screenshots do not clearly explain it as far as I can tell (and screenshots of text are poor form in any event). What command is behaving differently than you expect; how is it behaving; how would you expect it to behave?  In general if you're expecting `log` to tell you about the state of the working tree... well, that's not what `log` does.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: I want to `Trace the evolution of the line range`. Yes, this is `log` command. But not committed change is sort of evolution and should be taken into account by `-L` option. Currently I MUST `stash save` change, look actual line number, trace evolution, `stash pop` to bring back current change. `stash save/stash pop` commands are excess here. Current change maybe shown by `-L` as `commit NOT COMMITTED YET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the question is why `git log`s `-L` option doesn't show differences that are not committed.

The simple answer is that `git log` shows information from the commit logs, and until you commit (or stash) your changes there is no information about those changes in the commit logs.

In comments you say that an uncommitted change is still an evolution of the file.  Well, ok, but `git log` traces the evolution of the specified lines *through the commit logs*.  Maybe that's not as useful to you, or doesn't meet your definition of what git "should" do, but it is what git does.

So is the point to debate git's design choices, or make a feature request of git?  Not much use doing that in an SO question.

If you want a work-around... Making a stash is probably as simple a solution as you'll get, assuming it's working for you.  I guess you could write a script to make the stash, run the log command, and pop the stash (or otherwise create "temporary" commits representing your uncommitted changes) to save the couple commands' worth of typing

Comment: A script will not be useful, because It should `save stash`, stop processing, wait actual line numbers, continue...

Comment: I just thought that I miss some option that tell `git log` to show lines evolution for changed but not committed file. Thus if there is no such option I will post feature request. Thanks